# How do I find the minimum value in the right subtree of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to make a deletion function in Binary Search Tree.
I have finished with the deletion function, but I'm having some trouble with the FindMin() function as follows:

```
BST* delete_node(BST* root, int key)
{
BST* temp;
if (root == NULL)
    return root;
else if (key < root->key)
    root->left_child = delete_node(root->left_child, key);
else if (key > root->key)
    root->right_child = delete_node(root->right_child, key);
else //If the key is found delete it according to the following cases
{
    if (root->left_child == NULL && root->right_child == NULL)
    {
        free(root);
        root = NULL;
    }
    else if (root->left_child == NULL){ //right child exists
        temp = root;
        root = root->right_child;
        free(temp);
    }
    else if (root->right_child == NULL){ //left child exists
        temp = root;
        root = root->left_child;
        free(temp);
    }
    else{
        temp = FindMin(root->right_child);
        root->key = temp->key;
        root->right_child = delete_node(root->right_child, temp->key);
    }
}
return root; /*Returning the address of node to be reattached to 
            the parent of the deleted node*/

}

BST* FindMin(BST* root) //This functions finds the minimum key value in the 
right subtree
{
BST* temp = NULL;
if (root->left_child != NULL)
{
    temp = FindMin(root->left_child);
    return temp;
}
else
    return root;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm going to need to fix the FindMin() function to make this work. But I am having trouble with my delete function because every time I delete one node, it gives an error, and I think it's because of FindMin().

Comment: Have you *tested* `FindMin()`? It finds the minimum node in the tree. If you want the minimum node in the right sub-tree, call `FindMin(root->right_child)`.

Comment: I have tried for a couple of hours though..
I have occasional run-time errors from the code whenever I execute the program.
I do not see any logical error from the code but something is wrong.
And yes, I have tried FindMin(root->right_child) in the delete_node function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I am doing Binary Search Tree.

This is the structure:

```
struct _Node;

typedef struct _Node* Position;

struct _Node
{
    int element;
    Position left;
    Position right;
};
```

And this is the function for searching min value:

```
Position SearchMin(Position P)
{
    while(P->left != NULL)
    {
        P = P->left;
    }
    return P;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works:) Just had problem with dealing with the last NULLs that I always encounter when reaching down to the smallest value node in the Binary Search tree.